# Alogorithm to generate position of child in tree without overlap in js

Tags: javascript, tree, hierarchy, cytoscape.js

[image]

I have the following hierarchy representation, i need to generate position manually for each node in hierarchy so it looks clean.

The parent position for reference is 0,0, the canvas can take negative positions as well. the child position to be calculated is based on root parent position.

Comment: I know it's been long time but you can use dagre or klay layouts. https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape.js-dagre/ https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre